# QProxyStyle align QTreeView header with branch

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qstyle

I'm creating a QProxyStlye and would like to align the first header column with the items in the column.
Normally the first column starts with (0,0) and the items is offset by the width of a possible branch indicator (red square in the image).

[image: QTreeView]

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#rootIsDecorated-prop - false

Comment: @SaZ I need the branch indicator space to draw indicators but I want to change the alignment of the header. In the final style it would look great, not so with the Windows style.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Simple way is to inherit `QHeaderView` and override `paintSection` method. I'm not sure, that it is possible with delegates. If you really want to do this with `QProxyStyle` then you may research Qt code of `paintSection` method and find, what styles you need to reimplement.

Comment: Currently I tend to this ugly solution
`if(hopt->section == 0){
                // TODO: get width of a branch indicator
                rect.adjust(30,0,0,0);
            }`

Answer (score 0):

Create custom delegate for `QHeaderView`, override paint method.